# Internal search doesn't find questions when only part of tag is included

Tags: bug, search

I've checked a post on my phone, than tried to search for it in my pc, but didn't succeeded for first try:

[image]

After modification I've found it:

[image]

There was just a slight difference: first search term contained `Excel`. I'd expect superuser's search engine to find questions when search term only partially contains a tag name (e.g. `Excel` instead of `Microsoft-Excel` in this case).

Comment: I have a lot of trouble getting useful results from Stack Exchange search.  I usually try it, first; then half the time I end up using Google with `site:superuser.com`.

Comment: Search distinguishes between tags and content.  If you want to include a tag, it needs to be in brackets and be the correct tag name.  If it isn't in brackets, the word becomes part of the collection of search terms a post must contain.  In this case, there is no post that contains both the words in the title plus the word "excel".  However, [excel] is a synonym for [microsoft-excel], which is a tag that question includes, so including [excel] in the search string finds this question.

Comment: thanks fixer1234, it's more clear now. However I still think superuser's search engine should be more intelligent and find the question also in first case. I just can't memorize search rules for each site I use, and I think I'm not the only one...

Comment: @MátéJuhász - Its all a single search engine (thust all SE sites have the same rules), which means StackExchange, sounds like a SE feature request.